# How to get Facebook data in my Android app

Tags: android, api

I am developing one Android app in which there are two activities.

First activity: With button to go onto Facebook already login page. I want to know how to fetch data (like Name, DOB, Place, Email ID) from Facebook into my app.

Second activity (with EditText): How to match there API or what is required please let me know. I searched everywhere but did not find any answer.

I have done this, but it is showing errors.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

    facebook = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook);

    facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onClickFacebookLogin();

        //  Intent in = new Intent(FacebookActivity.this,GetDataFromFacebook.class);
        //  in.putExtra("email", );
        //  startActivity(in);
        }           
    });
}

    public void onClickFacebookLogin() {

        // Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {


            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    // make request to the /me API

                    //  ((GlobalFilename)Login.this.getApplication()).setfbSession(session);
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                Response response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                            if (user != null) {
                                final GraphUser graphuser=user;


                                try{    
                                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {         
                                        String fbemail,fname,lname,mediaid,image_url,gender,dob;
                                        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                                        ImageLoader imageLoader;
                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                            super.onPreExecute();

                                            if (progressDialog == null) {
                                                progressDialog = createProgressDialog(MyAccount.this);
                                                progressDialog.show();
                                            } else {
                                                progressDialog.show();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                            Object g = graphuser.asMap().get("email");
                                            if(g==null)
                                            {


                                                fbemail="";
                                                fname=graphuser.getFirstName();
                                                lname=graphuser.getLastName();
                                                mediaid=graphuser.getId();
                                                System.out.println("===>accountname inside null"+fbemail);

                                                return null;

                                            }
                                            else{
                                                fbemail= graphuser.asMap().get("email").toString();
                                                gender =graphuser.asMap().get("gender").toString();
                                                image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+graphuser.getId()+"/picture?type=square";
                                                //  image_url=String.format(image_url);
                                                //accountName =graphuser.getProperty("email").toString();
                                                System.out.println("fb email====>"+fbemail);
                                                fname=graphuser.getFirstName();
                                                lname=graphuser.getLastName();
                                                mediaid=graphuser.getId();
                                                dob=graphuser.getBirthday();
                                                System.out.println("Gender"+gender);
                                                System.out.println("Image==>"+image_url);


                                                try {

                                                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(image_url).openStream();
                                                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                                                    if(mIcon11==null)
                                                    {
                                                        System.out
                                                        .println("null in doinbackground");
                                                    }
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }



                                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                System.out.println("fb email====>"+fbemail);
                                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), accountName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                return null;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                                            super.onPreExecute();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            tvname.setText(fname+" "+lname);
                                            tvemail.setText(fbemail);
                                            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MyAccount.this);
                                            System.out
                                            .println("imageurlonpost==>"+image_url);

                                            // imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url,fbprofileimage);
                                            if (mIcon11 != null
                                                    ){
                                                // do what you need to do with the bitmap :)
                                                fbprofileimage.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this,"Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }.execute();
                                }catch(Exception e) {
                                    //findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook configuration error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },Arrays.asList("email"));
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

Showing errors at `new Session.StatusCallback()(under onClickFacebookLogin()) & getActiveSession() (at onActivityResult)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete working code.Set up your developer account and call this method.Also dont forget to call onActivityResult() once the control return from facebook.

```
//Method invoked when facebook login button is clicked
public void onClickFacebookLogin() {

    // Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
    openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API

                //  ((GlobalFilename)Login.this.getApplication()).setfbSession(session);
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                    // callback after Graph API response with user object

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                            Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                        if (user != null) {
                            final GraphUser graphuser=user;


                            try{    
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {         
                                    String fbemail,fname,lname,mediaid,image_url,gender,dob;
                                    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                                    ImageLoader imageLoader;
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        super.onPreExecute();

                                        if (progressDialog == null) {
                                            progressDialog = createProgressDialog(MyAccount.this);
                                            progressDialog.show();
                                        } else {
                                            progressDialog.show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        Object g = graphuser.asMap().get("email");
                                        if(g==null)
                                        {


                                            fbemail="";
                                            fname=graphuser.getFirstName();
                                            lname=graphuser.getLastName();
                                            mediaid=graphuser.getId();
                                            System.out.println("===>accountname inside null"+fbemail);

                                            return null;

                                        }
                                        else{
                                            fbemail= graphuser.asMap().get("email").toString();
                                            gender =graphuser.asMap().get("gender").toString();
                                            image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+graphuser.getId()+"/picture?type=square";
                                            //  image_url=String.format(image_url);
                                            //accountName =graphuser.getProperty("email").toString();
                                            System.out.println("fb email====>"+fbemail);
                                            fname=graphuser.getFirstName();
                                            lname=graphuser.getLastName();
                                            mediaid=graphuser.getId();
                                            dob=graphuser.getBirthday();
                                            System.out.println("Gender"+gender);
                                            System.out.println("Image==>"+image_url);


                                            try {

                                                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(image_url).openStream();
                                                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                                                if(mIcon11==null)
                                                {
                                                    System.out
                                                    .println("null in doinbackground");
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }



                                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), userid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            System.out.println("fb email====>"+fbemail);
                                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), accountName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            return null;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                                        super.onPreExecute();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        tvname.setText(fname+" "+lname);
                                        tvemail.setText(fbemail);
                                        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MyAccount.this);
                                        System.out
                                        .println("imageurlonpost==>"+image_url);

                                        // imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url,fbprofileimage);
                                        if (mIcon11 != null
                                                ){
                                            // do what you need to do with the bitmap :)
                                            fbprofileimage.setImageBitmap(mIcon11);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this,"Null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }.execute();
                            }catch(Exception e) {
                                //findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook configuration error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },Arrays.asList("email"));
}
```

Comment: Will it automatically fetch data or do i need something else too?

Comment: Just create the fb session and set up your developer account(i.e. implementing correct hash etc).Then call this method on button click.

Comment: Will it work like I just clicked the button in my activity and it will fetch data from facebook (not showing how it fetch) and directly falls on second activity (on EditTexts) with all the details required from facebook.

Comment: you have to store the data in a string and pass them to the next activity through intent.Study the code.